# Text overlapping in textbox

Tags: css

i have an issue in mobile view. That is text overlapping in textbox and selectbox also am used .form-control bootstrap class. am already tried the below properties,

```
padding-bottom: 10px !important;
line-height: 30px !important;
min-height: 50px;
display: flex !important;
white-space: normal;
overflow: visible;
```

but still same issue followed. Please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Either reduce line-height, or padding-bottom.

Comment: already tried. but no use

Comment: You need to inspect the element and check if your style gets overwritten by other, higher priority, selector